# Noether's normalization lemma in practice (example)

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I would like to know how to use the Noether's normalization lemma in practice.

> **Noether's normalization lemma**
>
> Let $k$ an infinite field, and $k[a_1,\dots ,a_n]$ be a finite $k$-algebra. There exist an integer $m\in\lbrace 0,\dots ,n\rbrace$ and $\lbrace b_1,\dots ,b_m\rbrace$ such that :
>
> 1. $\lbrace b_1,\dots ,b_m\rbrace$ is algebraically independent over $k$;
> 2. $k[a_1,\dots ,a_n]$ is a finite $k[b_1,\dots ,b_m]$-module.

I am working on the example
$$k[X,Y,Z]/\left<XY+YZ+XZ\right>=k[a_1,a_2 ,a_3]$$
with $a_1=\overline{X}$, $a_2=\overline{Y}$ and $a_3=\overline{Z}$. Let the morphism
$$\varphi : k[X,Y,Z]\longrightarrow k[a_1,a_2 ,a_3]$$
defined by $\varphi (X)=a_1$, $\varphi (Y)=a_2$ and $\varphi (Z)=a_3$ (as in the proof).

We have $XY+YZ+XZ\in \ker\varphi$, hence $\ker\varphi \neq \lbrace 0\rbrace $. So as in the induce process of the proof, I note

$$\varphi' : k[X,Y]\longrightarrow k[a_1,a_2]$$
define by $\varphi' (X)=a_1$ and $\varphi' (Y)=a_2$. Let $g\in\ker \varphi '$ so $\overline{g(X,Y)}=\overline{0}=\left<XY+YZ+XZ\right> =\lbrace (XY+YZ+XZ)h(X,Y) \mid h\in k[X,Y]\rbrace$.

If $g\neq 0$, for all $h\in k[X,Y]$,
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}[ll]
&\mathrm{deg}_Z (XY+YZ+XZ)h(X,Y)=1 & \text{if } h\neq 0 \\
\deg_Z g =0 & 
\end{array}\right.$$
And if $h=0$ then $(XY+YZ+XZ)h(X,Y)=0\neq g$. So $g\not\in\overline{0}$ absurd. So $g=0$ and we get that $\ker\varphi '=\lbrace 0\rbrace$.

Conclusion: I take $m=2$ and $b_1=a_1$, $b_2=a_2$ and using the Noether's normalization lemma I get that

1. $\lbrace a_1, a_2\rbrace$ is algebraically independent over $k$;
2. $k[a_1,a_2 ,a_3]$ is a finite $k[a_1,a_2]$-module.

> **Questions**
>
> Is my proof correct ? And more importantly is it this way that in practice we use the Noether's normalization lemma ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your "proof" that $\ker\phi'=0$ seems not to make sense. ALso, what you wrote seems not to include a proof of the scond point.

Comment: I didn't provide a proof of 2. because it is automatically true since we have $\ker\varphi' =\lbrace 0\rbrace$ (using the exact same arguments than in lemma's proof).

Comment: Well, since you did not tell us *what* proof of the lemma you have in mind, it is impossible to know.

Comment: If $\ker\varphi' =\lbrace 0\rbrace$ , we can show that $a_3$ is an algebraic integer over $k[a_1,a_2]$, 2. follows.

Comment: Are you sure about 2, the module finiteness? I did not see an argument.

Comment: $k[a_1,a_2,a_3]=k[a_1,a_2][a_3]$ is a $k[a_1,a_2]$-algebra generated by $a_3$. So since $a_3$ is an algebraic integer over $k[a_1,a_2]$, this implies that $k[a_1,a_2,a_3]$ is a finite $k[a_1,a_2]$-module.

Comment: Be careful. I assume you meant $a_3$ is algebraic, not algebraic integer. Algebraic does not imply finite module, true only if you are working over fields and $k[a_1,a_2]$ is not a field.

Comment: Yes sorry in French we use "entier algébrique" I mixed up. I meant algebraic. I'm using that : Let $A\subset B$ two rings, $B$ is a $A$-module finite if and only if $B$ is a finite $A$-algebra generated by algebraic elements over $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out where my mistake is. (I answer my own question in case someone run into the same problem.)

$\ker \varphi \neq\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is okay. But to continue I need that $a_3$ be an algebraic integer over $k[a_1,a_2]$, so I need a monoic polynomial $g\in k[a_1,a_2][X]$ but that isn't always exist. What is true is that if $g\in\ker \varphi$, there exist suitable $\alpha ,\beta\in k$ such that $g(X+\alpha Z,Y+\beta Z, Z)$ is monoic in $Z$. In this example $\alpha =1$ and $\beta =0$ suit.
So $a_3$ is an algebraic integer over $k[a_1-a_3,a_2]$, and only now I consider
$$ \varphi ' : k[X,Y] \longrightarrow k[a_1-a_3,a_2]$$
One can prove that $\ker \varphi ' =\lbrace 0 \rbrace $, hence using Noether's normalization lemma we get that $k[a_1,a_2,a_3]$ is a finite $k[a_1-a_3,a_2]$-module and $a_1-a_3,a_2$ are algebracally independent over $k$.